# ASP.NET Forms Authentication from Remote Server Okay?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, azure

I have a Visual Studio solution that consists of an ASP.NET website and a Lightswitch (soon to be 2 LS apps). I have configured everything so that a single login allows the user access to both apps. Currently both apps and the aspnetdb database are all on one machine.

Eventually, I want all three apps to be Azure websites with authentication via an Azure SQL database.

I want move the aspnetdb authentication database to an Azure and deploy the second LS app as an Azure website. Eventually the other 2 apps will be migrated to Azure, but in the meantime they will remain on the old server.

My question is are there any extra security issues I should be concerned with this arrangement? I have never had authentication and websites on different servers.

Comment: Did you use aspnet_regsql.exe to create aspnetdb?

Comment: Yes, I used aspnet_regsql.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are extra security issues as long as you're happy with the security around the connectivity to the SQL Database (which is based on HTTPS).

I do, however, think you should consider using Windows Azure Active Directory instead which will offer a potential cost saving and reliance on recent standards for authentication. if you haven't already look at this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx). it does not talk about LS but rather an MVC application, but you should be able to see the setup process

Comment: Thanks, Yossi. I had not considered Windows Azure Active Directory, but it sounds like a good idea. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

*You replied my question late, and accepted the answer. Anyhow, I'll answer your question so that this might be able to safe your time in the future.*

If you want to host in Azure, you should not use **Legacy Membership Provider** (in which tables are generated using **aspnet_regsql.exe**).

Instead, you want to use new **[ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)** which is SQL Azure compatible.

> any extra security issues I should be concerned with this arrangement?

You can configure to allow certain IP address(es) to access to your SQL Azure DB from outside of Azure. However, if someone knows your SQL Azure's username and password, they can access your Database within Azure.

Basically, you should be fine as long as nobody know your SQL Azure DB's username and password.

Comment: Please accept my apology for not not seeing your comment before I accepted the other answer. I DO appreciate you taking the time to provide me with some very useful information.